# how to prevent /:name for executing when other route is requestsed

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 routes: `/:name` and `/account`.

the `/account` route is loaded before the `/:name` route. is there a way to not execute `/:name` when any other route is found? Also, `/:name` should not execute when a request is for example `domain.com/username/..something`.

Comment: What? Please give a [mre] rather than a vague description. Take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: the order of routes registration is important. just register `/account` route before `/:name`. another option is to detect in `/:name` if the route is `/account` then call `next`